# How can I get the combo box selected from the user, and calculate that to the end result?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make the program calculate a user's selected item from combo box? i.e nothing happens when I select the type of wood, the fees won't add in.

```
woodType = cboWoodType.SelectedText;
if (woodType == cboWoodType.Items[2].ToString())
{
    price = price + MAHOG_FEE;

    MessageBox.Show("There is a $150 fee for Mahogany Wood.");
}
else if (woodType == cboWoodType.Items[3].ToString())
{
    price = price + OAK_FEE;
    MessageBox.Show("There is a $125 fee for Oak Wood.");

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(cboWoodType.Items[1].ToString());
}
```

Comment: do you have an event configured when the user clicks on the checkbox?

Comment: sorry, im completely new to programming. I dont think I  do, Ill google how to do an event configure thank you.

Comment: Select combobox at designer, press F4, click on lightning icon, find selectedIndexChanged and double click to the textbox near it. Write your code inside autogenerated code block. @JasonLam

Comment: Note sure if this is a problem too, but since you mentioned you are completely new to programming: Indexing in C# starts with `0` but I only see `1` to `3` in your code. Is `Items[0]` some kind of blank *"Select wood type"* entry or is it missing?

Comment: Btw, it might be easier for you to use `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedText`

Comment: yea, thats exactly what it is @ManfredRadlwimmer I have 0 as Wood Type on the Combobox, and the other 3 is Pine, mahogany, and oak. i tried what berkay suggested but no beuno.

Comment: Nothing happens? From your code, you should get at least a MessageBox to show up because all your branches end with one.

Comment: sorry, yea the messageboxes, pop up but it seems to skip the 2 if and goes straight to show me "Pine" which is what I have for index 1. I.E when I select mahogany it gives me pine. @ManfredRadlwimmer

Comment: Are you familiar with debugging yet? If you click slightly left of the line number (in the gray area) you can add a "breakpoint" to your code which will halt execution and allows you to find out whats wrong. Add a breakpoint (Red circle appears) to the first "if" condition, run your code until it hits the breakpoint and hover `woodType` to see it's actual value. Then you can step through your code line by line by pressing F10.

Comment: Btw, when asking questions about C# it's always helpful to include a tag to indicate if you are using `[WPF]`, `[WinForms]`, `[Mono]` ,`[Xamarin]` or something else. Also when something *"doesn't work"*, include details about what happens and what you would expect to happen and some code to reproduce the problem, or as we call it on SO: a [mcve].

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ah sorry, will do and this is WinForms if you havent guessed already. thank you so much for your help, im year 1 first quarter have zero programming experience. we haven't learned debugging yet. your right, my woodtype isnt saving the value when someone selects the text.

Comment: Try this: `int woodIndex = cboWoodType.SelectedIndex;` and `if(woodIndex == 1)` etc.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I ended up putting this "woodType = this.cboWoodType.GetItemText(this.cboWoodType.SelectedItem);" instead of the "woodType = cboWoodType.SelectedText;" and its working now. thank you soooo much!!! I was literally stuck with this for 2 days, and your comment helped a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help.